# Returns error when consuming this php response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Return error in the query

From the browser the answer is correct.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        async: true,            
        contentType: " charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "XMLHttpRequest",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        }
    });
```

The message says "error".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three issues. First, `dataType` is a choice of xml, json, script, or html, unless you did something really fancy. jQuery can guess it based on received data though, so there is normally no need to set it. But if you want to be explicit (assuming your page returns json):

```
dataType: "json"
```

Second, `contentType` value looks like some truncated thing. I would just completely remove it, as you are not sending any data and just requesting a page.

Finally, when you are sending no data and just requesting a resource, the best is to use GET.

All in all:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    async: true,            
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the considerations.

I tried and I continue with the same error.

Comment: @Chafaina: I just tried with this answer's example, replacing the `url` with yours, and I get this response (a partial example, this is not the whole content, as the size of a comment is limited) `{"0":{"nroSiniestro":"1","nombreTipo":"Incendio","fechaSalida":"2018-09-09 00:00:00","fechaRegreso":"2018-09-10 00:00:00","apellidoYnombreDenunciante":"Juliana Awada"},"1":{"nroSiniestro":"2","nombreTipo":"Accidente","fechaSalida":"2018-09-10 00:00:00","fechaRegreso":"2018-09-10 00:00:00","apellidoYnombreDenunciante":"Juana Deroper"}`

Comment: @Chafaina based on the info Paul found, I've change html to json in my answer.